# Can I truncate inventory_source_item table?

Tags: database, inventory, multi-source-inventory

I deleted all the products in the admin, but I noticed that the table **inventory_source_item** is still full of all the products that do not exist anymore. So, I suppose deleting the products does not delete the relation of product stock in this table. Can I truncate it safely?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not recommended to directly manipulate the database tables without understanding the impact it may have on your application. Truncating the inventory_source_item table can potentially cause data integrity issues, especially if your application relies on this table for any inventory-related functionality.

Instead of truncating the table, you can try using the command line interface or API provided by your e-commerce platform to update the inventory information. This way, the changes will be reflected in both the inventory_source_item table and any other relevant tables.